# Are you yoitze the Mitzva of Pirya Verivya with children born out of wedlock

Tags: children-parenting, aseres-hadibros

I know there is a machlokes Rishonim (rambam / Rosh) if Kedushin is a Mitzva or Hecsher Mitzva for Pirya Verivya. Say one has children out of wedlock, is that Mitzva fulfilled or do we say its a Mitzva Haba Bavaira?

Comment: Even if it were considered a mitzva haba b'aveira, he would still be considered to have already fulfilled it, as we see that a ger who had children before he was megayer is considered to have fulfilled it (even though he's otherwise considered k'katan shenolad dami and as a goy he had no such commandment).

Comment: http://ph.yhb.org.il/14-06-06/

Answer (score 12):

*Aruch Hashulchan* 1:17:

> Even if he has a son and daughter from an unmarried woman whom he did not marry with *chupa* and *kidushin*…, nonetheless he has fulfilled the command of *p'ru urvu*… for, after all, they are his offspring and fit to have children.

Answer (score 11):

The Rema in [Even Ha'Ezer 1:6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7487) writes that one fulfills the mitzvah of p'ru u'revu with a child who is a mamzer, which by definition is out of wedlock:

> היה הבן ממזר... קים המצוה
>
> If the child is a *mamzer*, he fulfills the mitzvah.

Minchas Chinuch Mitzvah #1 explains that it is not a *mitzvah haba b'aveira* using the idea of the Shaar HaMelech Hilchos Lulav 8:5, that a *mitzvah haba b'aveira* only undermines the fulfillment of a *mitzvah* when the *aveira* is done at the time of the fulfillment of the *mitzvah*, which is not the case by *p'ru u'revu* which is only fulfilled when the child is born. Minchas Chinuch supports this assertion with the fact that one is not considered to have fulfilled his obligation if he has not borne children, or the children did not survive, no matter how many times he has cohabited with a woman.

Comment: Technically, the father could be a mamzer and marry a mamzeres (or giyoret) and the child would be a mamzer without any new aveira being violated.

Comment: That is what i thought, but my question is really why is it not considered a Mitzva Haba bavira (im talking in a case where there is no Kedushin or a isur erva)

Comment: @Loewian The words of the Rema, however, sound like it is the child who is the Mamzer.

Comment: @EdRosenberg I edited to address that point. You should be clearer in your question posts about what exactly you mean to ask.

Comment: @Loewian Yes, but the Rema says it unconditionally.

Comment: @yEz If that's the reasoning, why not infer it already from halacha ה?

Comment: @yEz (I agree with you that that is what the Rama means. I just take issue with the proof. +1 anyway esp. for the Minchas Chinuch.)

Comment: ty@yEz Just so Im clear, If I steal a pair of Tefillin  on Monday, and I use  the tefillin on Tuesday - that is MHB because as long as its in my possession I'm doing something wrong - am I correct? Ty for your insightful answer

Comment: @EdRosenberg The Shaar Hamishpat makes that point explicitly - as long as you still have the stolen property in your possession, you are transgressing "והשיב את הגזילה" and it is a MHB. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14144&st=&pgnum=117&hilite=

Comment: @yez excellent - ty

Comment: I asked this in my own question and was referred here as duplicate; what if the child is from an adulterous reationship?